# Why am I getting exception as I try to read .DOCX file?

Tags: java, apache-poi, noclassdeffounderror, docx

While trying to read `.docx` file using the following snippet :

```
public void parseDocxFile(String textEntered) {
    try {
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(new File(SContainer.getFilePath())));
        XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
        System.out.println("DOCX File : " + extractor.getText());
    }catch(Exception exc) {exc.printStackTrace();}
}
```

I get an exception, which says :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache
/xmlbeans/XmlException
at org.suhail.gui.Main.parseDocxFile(Main.java:246)
at org.suhail.gui.Main.jButton1ActionPerformed(Main.java:167)
at org.suhail.gui.Main.access$000(Main.java:22)
at org.suhail.gui.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:71)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6038)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3260)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5803)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2058)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4410)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2116)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4322)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3986)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3916)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2102)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2429)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4240)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:273)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:183)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:173)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:168)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:160)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
```

What does it mean ? Why does it occur ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your classpath is missing a library, [xmlbeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/). Check the POI's [*Component Map*](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html) page.

Reassuming:

1. you need [`poi-ooxml`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cpoi-ooxml%7C3.10-FINAL%7Cjar)
2. `poi-ooxml` depends on [`poi-ooxml-schemas`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.poi%7Cpoi-ooxml-schemas%7C3.10-FINAL%7Cjar) (see the `dependencies` tag)
3. `poi-ooxml-schemas` depends on [`xmlbeans`](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.xmlbeans%7Cxmlbeans%7C2.6.0%7Cjar)

So you have to add the [xmlbeans jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/apache/xmlbeans/xmlbeans/2.6.0/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar).

Comment: What `jars` are required to read and write a `docx` file ? It is very confusing. I lack in its terminology

Comment: Added a link. All POI's stuff is really intricate, I'd suggest you of using **Maven** for dependencies handling.

Answer (score 1):

Add  [xmlbeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) on your classpath.

[NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) explanation:

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to
> load in the definition of a class (as part of a normal method call or
> as part of creating a new instance using the new expression) and no
> definition of the class could be found.
>
> The searched-for class definition existed when the currently executing
> class was compiled, but the definition can no longer be found.